# Is there anything more important than !important in css?

Tags: css, wordpress

It seems like my wordpress theme is adding a font color by default with !important condition and it appears as inline style. It targets not exactly what I need, so is there anything I can do about it? I already tried !important !important :)

Comment: There isn't an `!important !important`.

Comment: Is editing the theme out of the question? :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The only thing that could override an inline style with `!important` is a child element's style:

```
<div style='color: red ! important'>
     <span style='color: green'>This is green.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't override in terms of specificity, rather in terms of inheritance. But yeah. The idea is to wrap its contents in another element then toss the inline override into that element.

Answer (score 0):

you can override inline html style with:

```
div[style] { color: red !important; }
```

Comment: But it won't override an inline style with `!important`.